# Oracle Apex - How to Auto Access your Oracle Apex Development Environment

Tags: session, oracle-apex, builder, developer-tools

### **SCENARIO - PLEASE CHECK UPDATE BELOW**

- **Oracle Apex Builder** session is expired.
- You have to :

  - Re-login to workspace.
  - Open Builder.
  - Open current Page you are
    working on.
  - Open SQL Workshop ( almost always ).
  - Open SQL -> object browser ( almost always ).

Those Tasks takes **TOO MUCH TIME** Let's **Automate it !**

Attached below is a pretty **quick and easy solution** based on [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) ( served as is, you may custom it upon needs ) of :

**How to Automatically Open Oracle Apex Builder Environment using AutoHotKey**

Answer (score 0):

### **WHAT**

Using [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/), it will :

- **AutoLogin** with your Oracle Apex Credentials.
- **Open Multiple Browser** Tabs with ( **Application Builder**, **Page you are working on**, **SQL Workshop**, **SQL Object Browser**).

### **HOW**

- Download and Install [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
- Download [N/A Anymore] file
- **Edit** MyApexLogin.ahk file with notepad ( You **Must Customize Before double clicking** )
- Change the following lines :

  - Replace the following with your **hostname and Apex link if needed**  ( e.g /pls/apex )

    ```
    v_HostName = http://<hostname>:8080/ords/
    ```
  - Replace "etay" ( workspace password )  with your **Apex Workspace Password**

    ```
    SendRaw, etay
    ```
  - Replace Link with your Oracle Apex Page **you are now developing**.
    to get the link ( **right mouse click** on page in application builder to see it )
- **DoubleClick** on MyApexLogin.ahk **after edited it.**

### **RESTRICTIONS & HEADS UP**

- Works for me with Chrome browser ( didn't check other browsers ).
- Check that Sleep time in MyApexLogin.ahk is suitable for you ( depends on your computer performance and Internet Speed).
- Change any other settings upon your need.

---

### **HEADS UP UPDATE**

As Credits for this script go to John Nemo, I was requested to remove this script as it became a sort of commercial use at : [Youtube Link](https://youtu.be/4FzPNJfOV2g)

Comment: That's, probably, nice for someone who needs it. I don't. How come? My sessions don't expire as I set timeout to 2 hours (as opposed to 30 minutes by default). And, if I don't do anything for 2 hours, so let it expire. Opening SQL Workshop and Object browser? You said, almost always. I said: never, literally. I use TOAD for such things, some other people may use other tools, such as SQL Developer. Works in Chrome; nice, but I use Firefox. Therefore, bravo for you - you did something I wouldn't manage in years (as I don't know how to do that), but - I just don't need such a thing ...